# Handling operations with large positive and negative numbers

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I have the following function:

```
import scipy.misc
import scipy.special

def wave_func(x, n): 
  pre = 1. / ((2**n * scipy.misc.factorial(n) * numpy.sqrt(numpy.pi))**.5)
  return pre * numpy.exp(-x**2 / 2.) * scipy.special.eval_hermite(n, x)
```

This function converges. I would like to perform a summation over this function for `{n, 0, 500}`. Preferably I would even like to have the maximum value for `n` to be even larger than `500`, i.e. `15000`.

Although the function convergers, the `pre` becomes very small and `scipy.special.eval_hermite(n, x)` becomes very large for large `n`. Python does not seem to be able to handle these values. Very small values are returned as `0.0` whereas the large values are returned as `inf`. Multiplying these individual results will return `0`.

A program such as `Mathematica` is able to output the result. How does this work? Are they not both limited by `float64`?

Does anybody have a solution or work around such that I will be able to evaluate my function for large `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica and similar programs are sensitive to the magnitudes of the numbers involved.  They rearrange factors so as to preserve accuracy: start with e^(-x^2/2) / pi^0.25, then loop i = 1 to n ... multiply by i, divide by x (or whatever is in a compatible loop within the hermite function), ...

They work to keep the magnitude of the value reasonably close to 1.0, which helps preserve the accuracy.  They'll do converging summations from the small end.  They'll ... well, there are several basic numerical analysis tricks.

Is that enough detail?

Comment: Some suggestions you offered will help me a little bit. However, I am still confused about how mathematica handles its floats with respect to python. For instance, `2 * 3.1 *10^615` is something mathematica handles with ease. Python however can not, while both should still be limited by `float64`, right? Which trick would one use to perform that kind of calculation?

Comment: I don't know how Mathematica, in particular, handles this.  Float64 is not an absolute limit; it's a representation choice.  Intel architecture also supports floats of 80 (extended) and 128 (quad) bits, so I suppose that Mathematica takes advantage of that when necessary.

Comment: Ha!  I found the link.  [Intel Xeon FP](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/differences-in-floating-point-arithmetic-between-intel-xeon-processors-and-the-intel-xeon)